# why does graphql-ruby's boolean type not return false on null value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

In the graphql-ruby repo the Boolean type looks like this:

```
GraphQL::BOOLEAN_TYPE = GraphQL::ScalarType.define do
  name "Boolean"
  description "Represents `true` or `false` values."

  coerce_input ->(value, _ctx) { (value == true || value == false) ? value : nil }
  coerce_result ->(value, _ctx) { !!value }
  default_scalar true
end
```

But when i query a boolean field which returns nil from database i get null.

[image: Note query]

In my note type i have directly coupled a graphql field with my boolean attribute in the database.

```
field :is_public, types.Boolean
```

Can someone please explain this and maybe come up with a solution that does not involve changing all the fields?

Answer (score 0):

The default `GraphQL::BOOLEAN_TYPE` returns nil whenever a non boolean value is given as seen here: https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/7f7e97cc2902046d485adcb6e8e6a5eb462b3faf/spec/graphql/boolean_type_spec.rb

So what might be happening here is that `types.Boolean` is still mapped to the old `GraphQL::BOOLEAN_TYPE` and not using your new override.